# How to combine different dataframes randomly by rows in R

Tags: r, rbind

I have the dataframes `Relaxed.swimming`,`Intense.swimming`,`Resting` and `Burst`. They share the number of columns (4 columns) but they differ in the number of rows. As an example:

```
Relaxed.swimming <- data.frame(Behaviour= "Relaxed.swimming",
                               disurge=c(0.015,0.908,0.345,0.489),
                               diheave=c(0.398,0.782,0.198,0.634),
                               disway=c(0.491,0.398,0.189,0.592))

Intense.swimming <- data.frame(Behaviour= "Intense.swimming",
                               disurge=c(0.015,0.908,0.345),
                               diheave=c(0.398,0.782,0.198),
                               disway=c(0.491,0.398,0.189))


Burst <- data.frame(Behaviour= "Burst",
                    disurge=c(0.015,0.908),
                    diheave=c(0.398,0.782),
                    disway=c(0.491,0.398))

Resting <- data.frame(Behaviour= "Resting",
                      disurge=c(0.015,0.908,0.345),
                      diheave=c(0.398,0.782,0.198),
                      disway=c(0.491,0.398,0.189))
```

I just want to combine them by rows (keeping the 4 columns). The point is that I want to combine them hundreds or thousands of times and I want to combine them randomly, that is, the order changes constantly (i.e. `rbind(Relaxed.swimming, Intense.swimming, Resting, Burst, Resting, Intense.swimming, Relaxed.swimming, Resting, etc)`). Although I want to combine them randomly, I want to keep proportions (the four vectors are replicate approximately the same number of times). The ratios don't have to be exactly 1:1:1:1 but they should be close.

I would like to get something like that:

```
> df
          Behaviour disurge diheave disway
1           Resting   0.015   0.398  0.491
2           Resting   0.908   0.782  0.398
3           Resting   0.345   0.198  0.189
4             Burst   0.015   0.398  0.491
5             Burst   0.908   0.782  0.398
6  Intense.swimming   0.015   0.398  0.491
7  Intense.swimming   0.908   0.782  0.398
8  Intense.swimming   0.345   0.198  0.189
9  Relaxed.swimming   0.015   0.398  0.491
10 Relaxed.swimming   0.908   0.782  0.398
11 Relaxed.swimming   0.345   0.198  0.189
12 Relaxed.swimming   0.489   0.634  0.592
13            Burst   0.015   0.398  0.491
14            Burst   0.908   0.782  0.398
15 Relaxed.swimming   0.015   0.398  0.491
16 Relaxed.swimming   0.908   0.782  0.398
17 Relaxed.swimming   0.345   0.198  0.189
18 Relaxed.swimming   0.489   0.634  0.592
.          .            .       .      .
.          .            .       .      .
.          .            .       .      .
```

How can I get a large data frame obtained from the random replication of the 4 mentioned dataframes?

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to do so

```
library(tidyverse)
df_list <- list(Relaxed.swimming, Intense.swimming, Burst, Resting)

sample(df_list, 1, size = 10) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thanks @Yuriy. It looks great. It keeps rows of each behaviour together. Do you know if your code keeps proportions more or less? It doesn't have to be `1:1:1:1`, but I don't want like this one `100:3:7:1` either...

Comment: You can check by comparing the results of `prop.table`on the original combined dataframe and the resampled dataframe.

Comment: I have just checked it and in your case, the proportions are `0:2:5:3`. Do you know a way of getting them to be more proportional?

Comment: proportions are approximately preserved `set.seed(0)
df_list <- list(df1 = Relaxed.swimming, df2 = Intense.swimming, df3 = Burst, df4 = Resting)
out <- sample(df_list, 1, size = 1000)
out %>% enframe() %>% group_by(name) %>% count`

Answer (score 3):

If the proportions need not be 100% identical then this `dplyr` solution should work:

First row-bind the four dataframes together:

```
library(dplyr)
All <- rbind(Relaxed.swimming, Intense.swimming, Burst, Resting)
```

Then group them by `Behavior`and draw a random sample of any size. Random samples normally keep internal proportions intact:

```
All_s <- All %>% sample_n(1000, replace = T)

All_s[1:10,]
          Behaviour disurge diheave disway
1  Intense.swimming   0.015   0.398  0.491
2           Resting   0.345   0.198  0.189
3             Burst   0.345   0.198  0.189
4  Relaxed.swimming   0.345   0.198  0.189
5  Intense.swimming   0.489   0.634  0.592
6             Burst   0.345   0.198  0.189
7  Relaxed.swimming   0.345   0.198  0.189
8           Resting   0.489   0.634  0.592
9           Resting   0.015   0.398  0.491
10 Intense.swimming   0.241   0.241  0.241
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris. One doubt, Does the code you propose keep all the rows from one behaviour together? I guess it does from your comments. This is very important in my case. I can't mix rows from different behaviours randomly.

Comment: On second thoughts, if you want to keep the proportions I should think you will need to use this: `All_s <- All %>% group_by(Behaviour) %>% sample_n(1000, replace = T) `--this does mix the rows randomly from different behaviors and, as it samples the whole dataframe randomly, it should keep the proportions intact!

Comment: Thanks Chris. However, I need to keep rows from each behaviour together when sampling. Each dataframe contains acceleration in three axes (rows `disurge`,`diheave` and `disway`) at a high frequency (12 data per second). The behaviour has sense only if I keep rows from one behaviour together when merging different behaviours together. Do you understand?

Comment: Then I think @Yuriy Saraykin's solution is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far might not do as much shuffling as the question asked for. From the example, desired output, it seems like the final result should have a bit more shuffling E.g., the dataframe `Burst` has three rows but in the example output there are only two rows with Burst next to each other. This function replicates the list of dataframes, combines them in a random order, and then optionally shuffles the rows one more time.

```r
random_replicate <- function(list_of_dataframes, n = 2, extra_shuffle = TRUE){
  n_frames <- length(list_of_dataframes)
  replicated <- replicate(n, do.call(rbind, sample(frames, n_frames)), simplify = FALSE)
  combined <- do.call(rbind, replicated)
  if (extra_shuffle) combined <- combined[sample.int(nrow(combined)),]
  return(combined)
}
list_of_dataframes <- list(Relaxed.swimming, Intense.swimming, Burst, Resting)

random_replicate(list_of_dataframes, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. You were right. I made a mistake in the code I give you. I have fixed it!! I will try your code ASAP and I will tell you something.

Comment: Heads up that what I posted will only randomize the dataframes in sets of 4 (e.g., you won't get three replications of Burst in a row). If you need that something like the following would be better `random_replicate <- function(list_of_dataframes, n = 2, extra_shuffle = FALSE){
  replicated <- replicate(n, list_of_dataframes)
  combined <- do.call(rbind, sample(replicated, size=length(replicated)))
  if (extra_shuffle) combined <- combined[sample.int(nrow(combined)),]
  return(combined)
}`